# How to get value in pivot table based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

given a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1, 10, -1], [1,  7, -2], [1, 3, 14], 
    [2, 11,  1], [2, -2,  2], [1, 13, 4]]
DfObj = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeUF0.png)

and the pivot table

```
pivot = DfObj.pivot_table (index=['A', 'B'])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygtW3.png)

I'd like to get the corresponding C-value to the highest B-value for each A-value, i.e. 4 and 1.

4 is the C-value corresponding to the highest B-value in category A=1.

I assume B-values are unique within each category A.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to pivot here. You can use `sort_values` and `groupby.tail`:

```
DfObj.sort_values(['A', 'B']).groupby('A').C.tail(1)

5    4
3    1
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Or using `last`:

```
DfObj.sort_values(['A', 'B']).groupby('A').C.last()
```

Another approach could be to use `GroupBy.idxmax`:

```
DfObj.loc[DfObj.groupby('A').B.idxmax().values, 'C']

5    4
3    1
Name: C, dtype: int64
```